# How to run Xcode C++ on iOS sumulator

Tags: c++, xcode, ios-simulator

How do I run C++ code, developed in Xcode, on the iOS simulator on a Macbook Pro?? Is C++ compatible with the iOS simulator? The command line has c++ but there is no option for iOS simulator on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix Objective-C code and C++ by using Objective-C++. All you need to do to start using Objective-C++ is to start with an Objective-C project, then rename a source file to have the extension `.mm` instead of `.m`. Objective-C++ files can then include plain C++ headers directly, and you can compile plain C++ sources as part of the same Xcode project.

[Here's a tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/) with more details.

Answer (score -1):

The simulator can run iOS apps, it can't run terminal applications that won't run directly on an iOS device.

Comment: This is not true.  You can launch whatever terminal apps you want in your simulator device: `xcrun simctl spawn booted /path/to/my/sim_cltool’ … If this were true, there would be no way to run log, launchctl, etc tools in the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

You can run C++ code in Xcode, but it'd be running on your Mac, not the iOS Simulator. Xcode when building for iOS (and therefore the simulator as well) only natively support Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: This is absolutely not true.  C++ is very much supported in iOS.